# Dropdown menu css to expand the width based on content

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I was trying to create a dropdown that had dynamic values, basically there are 5 text boxes and a drop down on a page and the dropdown gets the values from those textboxes. If the user enters some text that is bigger than the width of the drop down then it is skewed on IE.
I fixed that by select:hover{width:auto;position:absolute}. Now the problem is if the user enters values that are all smaller than the original size of dropdown it contracts, I want a way so that it doesn't contract and still expands. Any thoughts??

I am using dojo and javascript, cant use jquery.

Comment: Reason for downvote? Its just retarded when people downvote something they cant answer

Comment: Wasn't me but maybe because you didn't post any code?

Comment: I didn't downvote you either, but the question is extremely Google-able; so people probably think it is a lazy question.

Comment: I found a lot of solutions on google that handle the long select items, but my question is specific ... and I am yet to find a solution on this one

Comment: The most simple solution if I have read the question correctly would be to use the min-width property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width) like so - select { min-width: 50px; width: auto; } - This would allow the width of the control to expand as needed but not to fall below the minimum width you defined. This could be defined on the :hover state selector, but would work just as well (and I would suggest) on the element itself. IE8+ support, no JavaScript required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript find the max width of the text, if it is bigger than the dropdown's current width, change the width to the max width of the text.

This will work like you desire (width not contracting) when you change the text again, because the JavaScript will find the max width of the text to be less than the dropodown's, so the width will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix would be to pick a width for your Dropdownlist and set max and min lengths to your textbox values so you can control over the size of your submissions. Otherwise i could type in anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ill get you back to 0 on your question and provide a solution.

Use CSS.  On the select box set a width and even if the content in it is smaller it wont get smaller.

```
<select style="min-width:200px;" id="someUniqueIdentifier">
    /* Your dynamicaly generated options*/
</select>
```

Comment: An absolute width will also prevent the select element from getting wider if the option text is wider than the width you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution if I have read the question correctly would be to use the min-width property (developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width) like so - select { min-width: 50px; width: auto; } - This would allow the width of the control to expand as needed but not to fall below the minimum width you defined. This could be defined on the :hover state selector, but would work just as well (and I would suggest) on the element itself. IE8+ support, no JavaScript required.